# OpenCV - imshow() not responding while waiting for input from command window

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a program that sets up an image to record measurements through user input using the mouse. After showing the image with imshow(), I ask the user if they would like to crop. While waiting for input to the command window, the namedWindow is not responding, and if the user clicks the window before specifying whether or not to crop, the window takes that as the first point to use for cropping.

Is there a way have the command window and namedWindow work in unison?

**Constructor for measurment class:**

> ```
> MeasurementClass::MeasurmentClass(){
>
> SetWorkingDirectory();
> std::cout << "Before continuing, make sure image files are located in:\n\n  "
>           << "\"" + WorkingDirectory + "\"\n"
>           << std::endl;
>
> setfilename:
> SetFileName();            //uncomment after debug
> SetDate();
> Image = cv::imread(XrayFileName, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
> FinalImage = Image.clone();
> if(Image.empty()){
>     std::cout << "Image failed to Load. Ensure correct image name and file location.\n"
>               << std::endl;
>     goto setfilename;
> }
> GetDesktopResolution();
> ResizeImageForDisplay();
>
> FinalDisplayImage = DisplayImage.clone();
> cv::namedWindow(WindowName, cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
> cv::imshow(WindowName, DisplayImage);
> cv::waitKey(10);
>
> PromptForCrop();
> ```
>
> }

**PromptFor Crop()**

> ```
> void MeasurementClass::PromptForCrop(void){
>     std::cout << "Would you like to crop image? (y/n):  ";
>
>     std::string strCrop;
>     std::getline(std::cin, strCrop);
>     std::cout << std::endl;
>     char Crop = strCrop[0];
>
>     switch(Crop){
>         case 'y':
>         case '\0':
>             CropImage();
>         default:
>             break;
>     }
>
> }
> ```

**Bonus**

It has recently been brought to my attention that *goto* statements are terrible practice. In this situation, what is a good alternative to the *goto* statement.

Comment: OpenCV's namedwindow is for debugging purpose. If you want to do more complicated GUI, you'd better to use something like Qt. If you insist on pure opencv, I suggest you to take a look at this example code:    https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/ffilldemo.cpp

Comment: Yes, don't use `goto`. They make the code difficult to read and error prone. Here you can use something like: `do { ... } while(!Image.empty())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the cv::waitKey() return value to get user input. In order to do so, please give the image the window focus, not the command window otherwise it will not capture your key:

```
char c = 'q';
cv::Mat image = cv::imread( "C:/local/opencv30/sources/samples/data/lena.jpg" );

cv::imshow( "image", image );

do
{
    c = cv::waitKey();
}
while ( c != 'y' && c != 'n' );

if ( c == 'y' )
    cout << "yes" << endl;
else if ( c == 'n' )
    cout << "no" << endl;
```

Comment: A good point, but other parts of the program use command window for user input. I think the real solution is a real user interface like Qt, as mentioned in the comments. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I would not recommend the highgui.lib for user interaction in real applications.